# Custom Sort on DimCalendar

Tags: sql

I have a DimCalendar dimension and I want to create a custom column on top of this which will be used as a "Sort By Column" in PowerBI report.

The sorting order should be Jan 2015, Jan 2016, Jan 2017, Feb 2015, Feb 2016, Feb 2017 and so on.

Hence, can someone help me write a SQL statement to create a column which will rank the numbers in the above sorting order?

Thanks.

**[UPDATE]**

Sample data - I have taken only first two dates from entire month.

[image]

Comment: No one can help if we don't now what `DimCalendar` looks like.

Comment: Its a DimDate dimension with all the dates from 2015 to 2017.

Comment: I want unique numbers for them in the derived column that I'll be creating. Not just Order by clause.

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The customer sort can be set by using the year and month.  In many databases, you can define it as:

```
update dimCalendar
    set customsort = month(date) * 10000 + year(date);
```

The ANSI standard syntax would be:

```
update dimCalendar
    set customsort = extract(month from date) * 10000 + extract(year from date);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate year part and month part of date.
In Ms SQL server you can use 
Datepart (year, date)+"/" + Datepart(month,date)